# Типы придаточных предложений 12

Tags: синтаксис

Укажите сложноподчинённое предложение с параллельным подчинением придаточных
(изъяснительного и причины).

1) В одной из поэтичнейших древнегреческих легенд рассказывается, что бог войны не смог однажды отправиться в поход, потому что в его шлеме свила гнездо и вывела птенцов белая голубка ***( последовательное подчинение)***. ***Здесь второе придаточное (причинное) зависит от первого). Верно?***

2) Не поймешь сразу**( что не поймешь?),** чем пахнет майское утро,**( не поймешь почему?)** потому что воздух растворен необыкновенным благоуханием цветущих деревьев.**Здесь параллельное подчинение .  Верно?**

3) М.А. Шолохов утверждал **( что утверждал?),** что мир не отнять у тех **(у кого?),** чьи руки держали оружие и воспаленные губы осушали слезы на щеках осиротевших детей (чьи глаза?), так как их глаза видели и навсегда запечатлели в памяти ужасы прошлой войны. Последовательное подчинение.

Насколько я правильно рассуждаю? Есть ли ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Подходит пример 2,** так как в примере 1 последовательное подчинение, а в примере 3   есть последовательное и параллельное подчинение, но параллельное подчинение относится к другим видам придаточных.

(1) М.А. Шолохов утверждал , (2) что мир не отнять у тех (у кого?), (3) чьи руки держали оружие и воспаленные губы осушали слезы на щеках осиротевших детей (чьи глаза?), (4) так как их глаза видели и навсегда запечатлели в памяти ужасы прошлой войны.

Предложения 1, 2, 3 ― последовательное подчинение, предложения 2,4 и 2,3 ― параллельное подчинение определительного придаточного и придаточного причины.

Comment: Т. е. предложения 2,3 и 2,4 относятся к главному?

Comment: Здесь две цепочки: 1, 2, 3 и 1, 2, 4.  Предложение 1 является главным для 2, а предложение 2 является главным для 3 и 4.

Comment: Если так, как вы говорите, то можно ли говорить о параллельном подчинении? Ведь при параллельном подчинении все части относятся к главному.

Comment: Я думаю, что сложное предложение может быть комбинацией различных видов связи.

Comment: Вы правы. Это я знаю. Получается, предложения 2,4, 2,3 одновременно подчиняются и к главному?

Comment: Я так не думаю.  Подчинительная связь - это связь между ДВУМЯ предложениями. Поэтому у предложений 3 и 4 только одно главное предложение 2, предложение 1 для них главным не является и вообще с этими предложениями не связано.